# 3D point cloud reconstruction of a scene from 2 images

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, opencv, math, computer-vision

I know there is a lot of stuff and information about this theme in the internet and in the library but I'm stuck.

I'm trying to understand how to reconstruct a scene from multiple images as a point cloud with Python and openCV.

What I understand so far:

1. Detect feature points with the SIFT-Algorithm in all images
2. Find corresponding points with the brute force matcher or FLANN algorithm
3. Calculate the intrinsic camera parameters and undistort all images
4. Calculate the fundamental matrix

Questions:

1. Let's say I find a feature point with SIFT in a distorted picture at about (2,2). Then I calibrate the camera and distort the images. My feature point lies still on (2,2) but it should be at (1,1). Am I right? How can I do this? And what if I don't undistort my image?
    To understand what I mean see the picture. (Green line shows me the correct feature point and red the wrong one)
    [image: picture]
2. How can I calculate the point P(x, y, z) from the two corresponding points (x1, y1) in image1 and the point (x2, y2) in image2 and the calculated fundamental matrix?

Comment: if you do not un-distort image then you are casting the triangulation rays in wrong directions so their intersection will give you wrong 3D position in all 3 coordinates. You do not need to undistort the image itself but you need to cast the rays in the un-distorted  direction...